# Probability that integers chosen can represent the lengths of the sides of a triangle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, combinations, triangles

> Three integers are randomly chosen from $1$ to $5$ with repetition not allowed. Find the probability that the integers chosen can represent the lengths of each side of a triangle

I first found the number of ways to choose the three integers by $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways to choose three side lengths from the numbers $1$ through $5$.

Here's where I'm stuck. There are 10 combinations:

$${1,2,3}$$
$${1,2,4}$$
$${1,2,5}$$
$${1,3,4}$$
$${1,3,5}$$
$${1,4,5}$$
$${2,3,4}$$
$${2,3,5}$$
$${2,4,5}$$
$${3,4,5}$$

But now how do I know which combinations can represent the lengths of a triangle

Comment: $a<b<c$ form a triangle if and only if $a+b>c$ due to the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). So out of the $10$ listed by you only $3$ triples suffice.

Comment: @Aig: That seems like a complete answer to me.

Comment: @joriki You mean I should post it as an answer?

Comment: @Aig: I do. There’s nothing to add to it, and the question will just remain unanswered and clog the system unless someone posts that as an answer. Might as well be you :-)

Comment: @joriki Reasonable, will do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that there is a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ if and only if three [triangle inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) hold: $$\begin{cases}a+b>c\\b+c>a\\ c+a>b\end{cases}$$ In our case repetition is not allowed, so the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ are different, and we can arrange them: $$a< b<c.$$ And we only need to check if $$a+b>c.$$

You found all the triples. There are $\binom53=10$ of them. Only $3$ of them fit: $$2,3,4$$ $$2,4,5$$ $$3,4,5$$

All the others don’t fit. The triples of the form $1,b,c$ aren’t good, since always $1+b\le c$. And the triple $2,3,5$ is also bad: $2+3=5$.